# NgbTooltip doesn't trgigger on <td> element

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I'm trying to put `ngbTooltip` on `<table>` elements
I already encountered problems on `<th>` which as been fixed by using `container` thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52748740/why-does-adding-tooltips-to-column-heading-cause-angular-columns-to-jump-sideway).
The **problem** comes on `<td>` elements which **does not display any tooltip** and I can't find any answer following documentation.

```html
<tbody>
<ng-container *ngFor="let line of aggreg | sortByElement:filterField:ascending; let idx = index">
  <tr *ngIf="showLine(line)">
    <!-- tds without tooltips here -->
  </tr>
  <ng-container *ngIf="detailsSelected === idx && showLine(line)">
    <tr *ngFor="let color of getColors(line) | sortByElement:'count':'false'" class="subline">
      <!-- tds without tooltips here -->

      <!-- Tooltip doesn't display when condition is true -->
      <td ngbTooltip="foo" placement="left" *ngIf="conditionHere" class="..." (click)="redirect(line)">
        <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
      </td>
      <!-- Tooltip doesn't display when condition is true -->
      <td ngbTooltip="bar" placement="left" *ngIf="otherConditionHere" class="..." (click)="redirect(line)">
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      </td>
      <!-- Tooltip doesn't display when condition is true -->
      <td ngbTooltip="baz" placement="left" *ngIf="anotherConditionHere" class="..." (click)="redirect(line)">
        <i class="fas fa-camera"></i>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
</tbody>
```

Also adding `container="body"` doesn't fix for `<td>`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to trigger an event manually to display the tooltip ? Try to trigger it and check in your html if the tooltip code appears somewhere, it might be a css issue that can be tweaked by overloading some properties.

Comment: Swapping from ```<td>``` to ```<div>``` does display my tooltip but it's an ugly implementation

Comment: It's look like their hookup does not bind on ```<td>``` elements tbh

Comment: You could make a div inside the td, not instead of the td ?

Comment: @Random that's what I tried too (and it works on another page with undirect call of ```#MyToolTip```) but it doesn't display either, two possibilities, **CSS problem** (won't be able to upload global css as it's for professional purpose) **or direct use** of ngbTooltip (does not bind ```#MyTooltip```)